# Understand why Min. / Max. Through 2nd derivative test

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm struggling on how to understand through the 2nd derivative test whether a certain point is maximum or minimum.

Let's say I just found the 2nd derivative of a certain function -

$f''(x) = 6x - 3 $

And let's say 
$x = 3 $

Sub $x=3$ 
$f''(x) = 6(3) - 3 = 15 $

Since it's $ > 0 $ , then it's a minimum point at the value $ x=3 $

Now , I'm only memorising that when it's $>0$ then it's minimum and vice-versa .

What is the best way to understand when it's minimum and maximum so that I can save the memory in my brain for other Subjects . Hehe .

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Remember an easy example. If I'm not sure then I think about $f(x)=x^2$, which has obviously a minimum at $0$ and $f''(0)=2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an intuitive understanding of the second derivative test, you need an intuitive understanding of the second order derivative. I like to think about it the following way:

Draw the graph of $f$ on a piece of paper. Now take a pencil or some other long, thin object, and move it along the graph, as a tangent, form left to right. The second derivative tells you which direction the pencil is turing as you move. A positive second derivative meanss that the pencil rotates counter-clockwise, or rather, that the point (on the right side) of the pencil is turned upwards. A negative second derivative means that the pencil is turning clockwise, or that the point of the pencil is turned downwards.

Now think what happens on a minimum: The graph goes down, then it goes up. That means that if you follow this graph with a pencil past the minimum, it must have gone from pointing downwards to pointing upwards. That means it must have turned counterclockwise, so the second derivative is positive (or, at least, non-negative).

Comment: Good explanation! But you still need to remember that counterclockwise movements are positive while clockwise movements are negative.

Comment: That's why I also noted which way the tip of the pencil that points forward moves. One could also ditch the pencil entirely and note that the first derivative goes from negative to positive, thus it is increasing, thus _its_ derivative is positive. Also, denoting counterclockwise rotation as positive is standard, if you have done trig on the unit circle or rotational mechanics in the plane or anything else. So while it is another fact to keep track of, it is consistent with corresponding facts in other fields.